# How to Add a Calendar Date Picker to an Excel Spreadsheet using Java

Tags: java, excel, datepicker

As per my requirement I need to add calendar datepicker in Excel file (`.xls`) using Java. I dont know whether it's possible or not. Please guide me if any library is there to add datepicker to Excel file using Java program.

Comment: I doubt jquery could be used in Excel (so the tag seems to be wrong). If you are looking for a lib based on poi supporting datepicker, this is the wrong site. In case poi already supports it, could you show us what have you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure whether apache poi library supports to add date picker in excel file. Please suggest me any other libraries to add date picker in xlsx file through java program